# MySQL EXISTS and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables 'Comments' and 'Likes' and I can show all the comments that have been liked and order them by when the comments where added. What I can't seem to do at the moment is order the comments according to when they were liked.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments AS c 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM likes AS l 
    WHERE c.commentID=l.commentID)
```

Could anyone help me with the SQL to show the comments in order with the one that was most recently liked first and so on...

Just to add - I only want to show the comment once and avoid showing any comments that have not been liked.

Comment: What are your timestamps when a like was added called?

Comment: Is there any column storing datetime?

Comment: apologies yes - I have a column storing date (as datetime datatype) in both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple likes for a given comment, then you need an aggregation, such as:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comments c join
     (select l.commentId, MIN(likedate) as FirstLikeDate, MAX(likedate) as MaxLikeDate
      from likes l
      group by l.commentId
     ) l
     on c.commentId = l.CommentId
order by MaxLikeDate desc
```

Comment: This is likely to be much more efficient than jmillroy's answer. Grouping before joining means a smaller cross-product.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Not to mention the fact that I abhor queries that use hidden columns in the `select` clause, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Any other views on efficiency here? I of course want to use the most efficient way but jmilloy's answer is working well. Should I change to this code?

Comment: I've gone for this as I can understand why it's more efficient. Thanks for the help

Comment: Could I just confirm that the second 'l' after the bracket makes it available to the whole SELECT query whereas the first 'l' after 'likes' is only accessible inside the sub-SELECT query - is this correct???

Comment: @tommyd456 . . . Yes.  The scope of an alias is well defined, but the alias can be re-used.  I was actually going to leave the alias out of the inner query, when I noticed that the `select` clause has `l.commentId` -- it was faster to just add the alias than to fix both the select and group by clauses.

Comment: great! ...and finally - if I wanted to find display the order in order of popularity (most liked) is it simple to amend or should I ask a new question? thanks for you help by the way

Comment: Sorry that's a bit awkward as it means changing a few things - I will probably ask at a later date if I can't get it going.

Answer (score 4):

You want to join the tables.

```
SELECT comments.*
FROM comments JOIN likes ON comments.commentID = likes.commentID
GROUP BY comments.commentID
ORDER BY MAX(likes.date) DESC;
```

The `JOIN` makes rows with all of the fields from comments and likes. If you use `LEFT JOIN` it will include comments that have not been liked, but using a plain `JOIN` should do what you want.

The `GROUP BY` collapses rows so you only have one per comment.

The `ORDER BY` orders the rows by the like date. I used `MAX(likes.date)` because you will have potentially many like dates for each comment, and you want to choose a specific one. You could try `MIN(likes.date)` as well, depending on what you're looking for (most recently liked vs first liked).

Comment: +1 Beat me to it... :) You might want to add a `DESC` on the sort order for most recent first.

Comment: Hi - yes this will show comments multiple times if they have been liked multiple times. I only want to show a comment once.

Comment: @tommyd456 Hm, no, the group by (added by an edit) will make them show only once.

Comment: That's brilliant - it was the MAX function that I didn't consider using. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen you edit before my 1st comment. Added Group By and MAX and everything great

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to show the comments that have like, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN likes USING(commentID) ORDER BY like_date DESC;
```

Comment: If the comment has been liked multiple times, this will show the comment multiple times..